# How can I add href tags to HTML when using display:grid CSS?

Tags: html, css, grid, href, display

I managed to lay out this grid with images, text, and hover states -- but when I added an href to the grid it threw the entire thing off. I tried adding it around the parent div and the child div, no luck.

I'm fairly new to code, and I've had trouble executing this exact layout with :float or other display methods -- but way I'm open to any other ideas.

Here's the desired output
[image]

Below, see the code without the hrefs.

```css
.topic_grid { 
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px 15px;
  
}

.topic_item { 
}

.topic_item_content {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.topic_item:nth-child(1) {
  background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)
    ), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a38be65949102c557c8/1502317113592/stocks.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.topic_item:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a38914e6b9c8814769f/1502317126921/panic.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}


.topic_item:nth-child(3) {
   background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a39a803bbd59bdbc091/1502317116351/trump.jpg?format=1000w') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  height: 480px
}


.topic_item:nth-child(4) {
 background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a397131a56e0537287c/1502317117059/unemployment.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
  height: 300px
}

.topic_item:nth-child(5) {
 background: linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
    ), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8fd7f5e23155afd464f2/1502318554421/China-Flag-4.jpg') no-repeat left;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<div class="topic_grid">
  
  <div class="topic_item">   
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        Investing
    </div>
  </div>
 
    <div class="topic_item">
      <div class="topic_item_content">
      Panic <br>
        <span style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.3)">
          (Or Don't)
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  
    <div class="topic_item">
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        Trump
      </div>
    </div>
  
   <div class="topic_item">
    
    <div class="topic_item_content">
      Unemployment
    </div>
  
  </div>
  
   <div class="topic_item">
    
    <div class="topic_item_content">
      China
    </div>
  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: There are no links in your code...you might want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

### **jQuery solution**

If you insist on keeping the current structure, you can modify it like so,

add a `.sizer` div inside each `<div class="topic_item">`

example:

```
  <div class="topic_item">
    <div class="sizer">
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        Panic <br>
        <span style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.3)">
          (Or Don't)
        </span>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- /.sizer -->
  </div>
```

Then style `.sizer` like so:

```
.sizer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1
}
```

So that it measures the space available and the `z-index` helps keep things clean.

You can then use jQuery to [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the `<a>` tags around the `.sizer`

Like so:

```
$(".topic_item:nth-of-type(1)>.sizer").wrap("<a href='#1'></a>");
```

Then use different selectors to add different links.

**Working example:**

```js
$(".topic_item:nth-of-type(1)>.sizer").wrap("<a href='#1'></a>");
$(".topic_item:nth-of-type(2)>.sizer").wrap("<a href='#2'></a>");
$(".topic_item:nth-of-type(3)>.sizer").wrap("<a href='#3'></a>");
$(".topic_item:nth-of-type(4)>.sizer").wrap("<a href='#4'></a>");
$(".topic_item:nth-of-type(5)>.sizer").wrap("<a href='#5'></a>");
```

```css
.topic_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px 15px;
}

.sizer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1
}

.topic_item_content {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.topic_item:nth-child(1) {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a38be65949102c557c8/1502317113592/stocks.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 2;
}

.topic_item:nth-child(2) {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a38914e6b9c8814769f/1502317126921/panic.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-row-end: 3;
}

.topic_item:nth-child(3) {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a39a803bbd59bdbc091/1502317116351/trump.jpg?format=1000w') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 3;
  height: 480px
}

.topic_item:nth-child(4) {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8a397131a56e0537287c/1502317117059/unemployment.jpg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 4;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
  height: 300px
}

.topic_item:nth-child(5) {
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5891364f20099ec08ca009b7/58a8b1a7d2b8579b70b8e8ed/598b8fd7f5e23155afd464f2/1502318554421/China-Flag-4.jpg') no-repeat left;
  background-size: cover;
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-column-end: 6;
  grid-row-start: 4;
  grid-row-end: 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topic_grid">

  <div class="topic_item">
    <div class="sizer">
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        Investing
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topic_item">
    <div class="sizer">
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        Panic <br>
        <span style="color: rgba(255,255,255,.3)">
          (Or Don't)
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topic_item">
    <div class="sizer">
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        Trump
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topic_item">
    <div class="sizer">
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        Unemployment
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="topic_item ">
    <div class="sizer">.
      <div class="topic_item_content">
        China
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```